# webbrowser.document throws Specified cast is not valid exception

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I've got a WebBrowser control on my page. To fire some javascript on a page displayed in the browser control. and when i try to save my web page i got this error

```
String strHtml = _browser.Document.Body.OuterText;
File.WriteAllText("C:\saveme.html", strHtml);
```

and this line  _browser.Document.Body.OuterText throws the exception

```
Exception:: Specified cast is not valid.
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IHTMLDocument2.GetLocation()
at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.get_Document()....
```

i had also used Invoke but does't work , 
is there any thing i missed out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you accessing the WebBrowser control from the UI thread? If not, try to access it from the UI thread or use [Dispatcher.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604732.aspx). See ["Specified cast is not valid" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566337/c-sharp-specified-cast-is-not-valid-error) for more details.

Otherwise, the document probably has not completed loading yet. Wait until the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event has fired to ensure the document has loaded, then access the property. See  [WebBrowser.Document.Body is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141061/webbrowser-document-body-is-always-null) for more information.